# Reverse every k nodes of a linked list .. if linked list is 1-2-3-4-5-6-7 and k is 3 then it would become 3-2-1-6-5-4-7

Tags: c++

we have to reverse every k nodes of linked list example :- if linked list is 1-2-3-4-5-6-7 and k is 3 then it would become 3-2-1-6-5-4-7.
my code :-

```
class Pair {
    public:
    Node *head;
    Node *tail;
};

Pair reverse(Node *head) {
    if (head == NULL || head->next == NULL) {
        Pair ans;
        ans.head = head;
        ans.tail = head;
        return ans;
    }

    Pair smallAns = reverse(head->next);
    smallAns.tail->next = head;
    head->next = NULL;
    Pair ans;
    ans.head = smallAns.head;
    ans.tail = head;
    return ans;
}

Node *kReverse(Node *head, int k) {
    if (head == NULL) {
        return head;
    }

    if (k == 0 || k == 1) {
        return head;
    }
        
    Node *temp = head;
    int count = 0;

    while (temp != NULL && count == k - 1) {
        temp = temp->next;
        count++;
    }

    Node *head2 = NULL;

    if (temp != NULL) {
        head2 = temp->next;
        temp->next = NULL;
    }

    Node *newHead = kReverse(head2, k);
    Pair ans = reverse(head);
    ans.tail->next = newHead;
    return ans.head;
}
```

it is not working ... It is giving back the unchanged linked list..

Comment: Step through your code with a debugger. You should discover that your `while` loop has zero iterations; take a closer look at the conditional.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.